# How to display Attribute Group Name on Product page Magento 2

Tags: php, magento, magento2, magento2.2

I want to display attribute group name in product information tab, like it's done on admin panel. 
for example:

**attgroup1**
attribute1
attribute2
**attgroup2**
attribute3
attribute4

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way, will return all Attribute Group and attributes.

```
<?php
                $attributeSetCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_group_collection');
                $attributeSetCollection->addFieldToFilter('attribute_set_id', '4');
                foreach ($attributeSetCollection as $id => $attributeGroup) {
                    echo '<h3>group-name: ';
                    echo $attributeGroup->getAttributeGroupName();
                    echo '</h3><ul>';
                    $attributeCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')->setAttributeGroupFilter($attributeGroup->getAttributeGroupId());
                    foreach ($attributeCollection as $attribute) {
                        echo "<li>Attribute Frontend Label: " . $attribute->getFrontendLabel();
                        echo "</li>";
                        echo "<li>Attribute Name: " . $attribute->getName();
                        echo "</li></ul>";
                    }
                }
                ?>
```

**OutPut:**

```
group-name: Design
Attribute Frontend Label: Custom DesignAttribute Name: custom_design
Attribute Frontend Label: Active From
Attribute Name: custom_design_from
Attribute Frontend Label: Active To
Attribute Name: custom_design_to
Attribute Frontend Label: Custom Layout Update
Attribute Name: custom_layout_update
Attribute Frontend Label: Page Layout
Attribute Name: page_layout
Attribute Frontend Label: Display Product Options In
Attribute Name: options_container
group-name: General
Attribute Frontend Label: NameAttribute Name: name
Attribute Frontend Label: Description
Attribute Name: description
Attribute Frontend Label: Short Description
Attribute Name: short_description
Attribute Frontend Label: Article Number
Attribute Name: sku
Attribute Frontend Label: Set Product as New from Date
Attribute Name: news_from_date
Attribute Frontend Label: Set Product as New to Date
Attribute Name: news_to_date
Attribute Frontend Label:
Attribute Name: old_id
Attribute Frontend Label: Status
Attribute Name: status
Attribute Frontend Label: URL Key
Attribute Name: url_key
Attribute Frontend Label: Visibility
Attribute Name: visibility
Attribute Frontend Label: Country of Manufacture
Attribute Name: country_of_manufacture
Attribute Frontend Label: Featured
Attribute Name: featured
Attribute Frontend Label:
Attribute Name: url_path
Attribute Frontend Label:
Attribute Name: category_ids
Attribute Frontend Label:
Attribute Name: required_options
Attribute Frontend Label:
Attribute Name: has_options
Attribute Frontend Label: Image Label
Attribute Name: image_label
Attribute Frontend Label: Small Image Label
Attribute Name: small_image_label
Attribute Frontend Label: Thumbnail Label
Attribute Name: thumbnail_label
Attribute Frontend Label:
Attribute Name: created_at
Attribute Frontend Label:
Attribute Name: updated_at
Attribute Frontend Label:
Attribute Name: price_type
Attribute Frontend Label:
Attribute Name: sku_type
Attribute Frontend Label:
Attribute Name: weight_type
Attribute Frontend Label: Shipment
Attribute Name: shipment_type
Attribute Frontend Label: Links can be purchased separately
Attribute Name: links_purchased_separately
Attribute Frontend Label: Samples title
Attribute Name: samples_title
Attribute Frontend Label: Links title
Attribute Name: links_title
Attribute Frontend Label:
Attribute Name: links_exist
group-name: Gift Options
Attribute Frontend Label: Allow Gift MessageAttribute Name: gift_message_available
group-name: Images
Attribute Frontend Label: Base ImageAttribute Name: image
Attribute Frontend Label: Small Image
Attribute Name: small_image
Attribute Frontend Label: Thumbnail
Attribute Name: thumbnail
Attribute Frontend Label: Media Gallery
Attribute Name: media_gallery
Attribute Frontend Label: Image Gallery
Attribute Name: gallery
group-name: Meta Information
Attribute Frontend Label: Meta TitleAttribute Name: meta_title
Attribute Frontend Label: Meta Keywords
Attribute Name: meta_keyword
Attribute Frontend Label: Meta Description
Attribute Name: meta_description
group-name: Prices
Attribute Frontend Label: PriceAttribute Name: price
Attribute Frontend Label: Group Price
Attribute Name: group_price
Attribute Frontend Label: Special Price
Attribute Name: special_price
Attribute Frontend Label: Special Price From Date
Attribute Name: special_from_date
Attribute Frontend Label: Special Price To Date
Attribute Name: special_to_date
Attribute Frontend Label: Cost
Attribute Name: cost
Attribute Frontend Label: Tier Price
Attribute Name: tier_price
Attribute Frontend Label: Minimal Price
Attribute Name: minimal_price
Attribute Frontend Label: Apply MAP
Attribute Name: msrp_enabled
Attribute Frontend Label: Display Actual Price
Attribute Name: msrp_display_actual_price_type
Attribute Frontend Label: Manufacturer's Suggested Retail Price
Attribute Name: msrp
Attribute Frontend Label: Tax Class
Attribute Name: tax_class_id
Attribute Frontend Label: Price View
Attribute Name: price_view
group-name: Recurring Profile
Attribute Frontend Label: Enable Recurring ProfileAttribute Name: is_recurring
Attribute Frontend Label: Recurring Payment Profile
Attribute Name: recurring_profile
group-name: SAP Attributes
Attribute Frontend Label: Product BrandAttribute Name: vesbrand
Attribute Frontend Label: Brand
Attribute Name: extwg
Attribute Frontend Label: Units of Measurement
Attribute Name: zuom
Attribute Frontend Label: UOM Text
Attribute Name: zuom_text
Attribute Frontend Label: ZUNIT
Attribute Name: zunit
Attribute Frontend Label: Gross Weight
Attribute Name: zunit_text
Attribute Frontend Label: Net Weight
Attribute Name: zunit_text1
Attribute Frontend Label: Weight
Attribute Name: weight
Attribute Frontend Label: ZSTOR
Attribute Name: zstor
Attribute Frontend Label: Recommended Storage Temp From
Attribute Name: ztemp1
Attribute Frontend Label: Recommended Storage Temp To
Attribute Name: ztemp2
Attribute Frontend Label: Minimum Expiry Label
Attribute Name: zexp_text
Attribute Frontend Label: Minimum Expiry Value
Attribute Name: zexp_value
Attribute Frontend Label: Minimum Expiry
Attribute Name: zexpiry
Attribute Frontend Label: Expiry Life Text
Attribute Name: zlife_text
Attribute Frontend Label: Expiry Life Value
Attribute Name: zlife_value
Attribute Frontend Label: Expiry Life
Attribute Name: zself
Attribute Frontend Label: Minimum Order Weight
Attribute Name: zmin_wt
Attribute Frontend Label: Article Barcode
Attribute Name: barcode
Attribute Frontend Label: Health Statements
Attribute Name: zhealth_st
Attribute Frontend Label: Recommended Storage
Attribute Name: zstorage
Attribute Frontend Label: Ingredients
Attribute Name: zingredients
Attribute Frontend Label: Nutritional Facts
Attribute Name: znutritional
Attribute Frontend Label: Cooking Instructions
Attribute Name: zcooking
Attribute Frontend Label: Directions of Use
Attribute Name: zdirections
Attribute Frontend Label: Caution
Attribute Name: zcaution
Attribute Frontend Label: First Aid
Attribute Name: zfirst
Attribute Frontend Label: Formula
Attribute Name: zformula
Attribute Frontend Label: Ingestion
Attribute Name: zingestion
Attribute Frontend Label: Warning
Attribute Name: zwarning
Attribute Frontend Label: Actions
Attribute Name: zactions
Attribute Frontend Label: Results
Attribute Name: zresults
Attribute Frontend Label: Texture
Attribute Name: ztexture
Attribute Frontend Label: Features and Information
Attribute Name: zinformation
Attribute Frontend Label: Manufacturer Country
Attribute Name: manufacture_of_country
group-name: Subscription
Attribute Frontend Label: EnableAttribute Name: alw_sarp_enabled
Attribute Frontend Label: Period type(s)
Attribute Name: alw_sarp_period
Attribute Frontend Label: Enable shipping
Attribute Name: alw_sarp_has_shipping
Attribute Frontend Label: Subscription Price
Attribute Name: alw_sarp_subscription_price
Attribute Frontend Label: First period price
Attribute Name: alw_sarp_first_period_price
Attribute Frontend Label: On subscription, move to group
Attribute Name: alw_sarp_include_to_group
Attribute Frontend Label: On unsubscription/expiry, move to group
Attribute Name: alw_sarp_exclude_to_group
Attribute Frontend Label: Download access based on the subscription status: Yes/No
Attribute Name: alw_sarp_download_by_status
Attribute Frontend Label: Shipping cost
Attribute Name: alw_sarp_shipping_cost
Attribute Frontend Label: Allow guest subscriptions
Attribute Name: alw_sarp_subscription
Attribute Frontend Label: Change first period price according to selected product options
Attribute Name: alw_sarp_options_first_price
Attribute Frontend Label: Show "First delivery" calendar at product page
Attribute Name: alw_sarp_display_calendar
```

Comment: isn't this for magento 1?